# how to fix Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m, power-bi-report-server

I want to create a measure that concatenates a letter with a column that contains numeric values

here is the formula

```
measure = IF(
    FILTER('table',[D/C] = "C"),
    MAX('table'[Montant]),
    BLANK()
)
```

It returns this error "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Power Query and convert column Montant type to Text then try following measure

```
measure = IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('table'[D/C]) = "C",
    "C - " & SELECTEDVALUE('table'[Montant]),
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work :

Comment: Edited answer. Try now

Comment: test = 
IF(
    'table'[D/C] = "C",
    MAX('table'[Montant]),
    BLANK()
)
it returns this error it is not possible to determine a unique value for the column [D/C] of the table

Comment: Edited my answer. Try now

Comment: I convert column Montant type to Text, it doesn't work